# I have an gradle error everytime I run the app

Tags: android, gradle, manifest

I am working with an android project and every time I run the app there is an error of this type :

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91  is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).   Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-44:19 to override.

And even if I try to do it the way it told me there is another error.

This is the **build.gradle** file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.community.jboss.visitingcard"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
//the intro library
implementation 'com.github.msayan:tutorial-view:v1.0.6'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation "com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
 core:3.0.2'
}
```

And this is the **Manifest** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.community.jboss.visitingcard">

<!--
    TODO: Add location/GPS access permissions
    TODO: Change the Label of the Activities according to the Activity's 
context
    TODO: Change App Icon .i.e., ic_launcher
-->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".VisitingCard.VisitingCardActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".IntroScreens.SliderActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- TODO: Add Google Maps API key here -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Maps.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name=".VisitingCard.ViewVisitingCard" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
    <activity android:name=".IntroActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your manifest :

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
```

Like this :

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory>

//Your code here

</application>
```

Comment: Yeah when i tryed it it said Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: Have you added this line in manifest? `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"`

Answer (score 0):

You are using two appcompat dependencies one from support namespace and another one is from androidx namespace.Ideally solution would be move your project completely to androidx and remove the below mentioned dependency,

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

and you could use stable version of andoid x appcompat library

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0 instead of androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: But should I also remove     implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
and

Comment: and also     implementation "com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0"

Comment: You moved partially to androidx. replace com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0  with this  androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0

Comment: replace com.android.support.design:28.0.0 with com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01 Refer for more info https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate

Comment: I built the app with those gradle but now i have error on all the other files

Comment: You might need to follow the androidx migrartion if you really want to use androidx else fallbackback to android support name space and don't use androidx

Answer (score 0):

It seems you decided to use androidX in your project, but using `appCompat` with `androidX` together is incorrect.
It's better if you use androidX's libraries, remove appCompat ones.
If you insistent to use androidX remove `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` in `build.gradle` file or remove androidX one, otherwise.

for more information about your error :
You can open the "Manifest" file and go to merged tab. At the bottom of file you can see what are wrong.